# Adding custom property to every HTTP header in portlet

Tags: jboss, http-headers, portlet, jboss-portal, x-ua-compatible

I can't add the tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

to the `<header-content>` section in my `<portlet>` configured in the *jboss-portlet.xml* file because `<meta>` tags are not supported by JBoss.

I now want to add

```
X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
```

to every HTTP header on this portlet. Is this somehow possible?

For more information on `X-UA-Compatible` see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/06/10/introducing-ie-emulateie7.aspx.
I'm using JBoss 4.2.3.GA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [doHeaders(...)](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/GenericPortlet.html#doHeaders%28javax.portlet.RenderRequest,%20javax.portlet.RenderResponse%29) method that get's invoked when I set

```
<container-runtime-option>
    <name>javax.portlet.renderHeaders</name>
    <value>true</value>
</container-runtime-option>
```

in my `portlet.xml` (see [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0803_hepper/0803_hepper.html) for more details).

But unfortunately all the properties I set there are somewhere lost on the way to the client.